# Compile Git without gettext

Tags: git, gettext, msgfmt

I'm trying to compile a static Git 2.17.1 on Debian (Windows Subsystem for Linux):

```
$ mkdir _git
$ make configure
$ ./configure --prefix=$PWD/_git NO_TCLTK=true NO_GETTEXT=true CFLAGS="${CFLAGS} -static"
$ make all
```

but I'm getting the error

```
...
    MSGFMT po/build/locale/pt_PT/LC_MESSAGES/git.mo
/bin/sh: 1: msgfmt: not found
Makefile:2309: recipe for target 'po/build/locale/pt_PT/LC_MESSAGES/git.mo' failed
make: *** [po/build/locale/pt_PT/LC_MESSAGES/git.mo] Error 127
```

The information about `NO_GETTEXT` I have from the configure file:

```
# Define NO_GETTEXT if you don't want Git output to be translated.
```

Does it need `msgfmt` nonetheless?

Comment: That's not where you got the information about `NO_GETTEXT`, and that's not how you define variables for makefiles.

Comment: @jthill Well, then the question is *how* to do it right.

Answer (score 8):

This worked for me.

`make NO_GETTEXT=YesPlease`

Comment: `make NO_GETTEXT=YesPlease all` for specific target.

Answer (score 1):

Try with 1 instead of true...

https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/install-git

```
NO_GETTEXT=1
```

Comment: This works! But It will download things about, 1125 MB! The key installing is  that "sudo apt-get install gettext".

Comment: question is about compiling it, you are talking about installing the binary package with a package manager.

Comment: The solution you gave is solvable and successful, but more packages need to be downloaded.

I mean, the core of the solution to this problem is precisely the lack of this dependency package.

Answer (score 1):

The variable NO_GETTEXT is set by the configure script.  If your build host has the gettext runtime, it is set to false.

You have several options to work around this:

- Install the gettext tools (including msgfmt) on your build host.
- Install a dummy msgfmt that just creates an empty output file.
- `/usr/bin/touch` all `.mo` files before you run `make` and make sure that their last-modified time is more recent than that of the `.po` files.
- Patch the Makefile before you run `make`.  Setting the variable `MOFILES` to empty looks promising.

You probably have to patch the Makefile anyway, so maybe just go with the last option.

Answer (score -1):

Please install gettext:

```
sudo apt-get install gettext
```

Manually install Git needs:

```
sudo apt install make libssl-dev libghc-zlib-dev libcurl4-gnutls-dev libexpat1-dev gettext unzip
```